Add connectionString to webapplication builder without appsetting
I have a project that need use vault secret manager to save a connectionString and other credential so the connectionString is not use appsetting to confugire, for other credential is already working, but failed to apply to set a connectionString
I have explore the solution and not found any thing, and i just try below solution :
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    
    var map = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        ["ConnectionStrings:A"] = "conectionstring for A", //conectionstring for A will from secret manager
        ["ConnectionStrings:B"] = "conectionstring for B",//conectionstring for B will from secret manager
    };
    IConfiguration _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddInMemoryCollection(map!).Build();
    
    builder.Services.Configure<IConfigurationBuilder>(options => {
        options.AddConfiguration(_configuration);

});

and here is my DBContext
public class DbContext
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public SqlServerDbContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public virtual IDbConnection CreateConnection(string connectionName)
    {
        var connectionString = _configuration.GetConnectionString(connectionName);
        if (connectionString is null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Connection string for {connectionString} is not set.");
        }

        return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
}

Am I missing something or is there a other way to setting connectionString without appsetting.json?
I would be glad for any help.
